# App only calls for alerts, but displays badges anyway

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

My app only calls for alerts, but badges are showing up and won't clear. Here is the code....
:

```
- (void)registerForAPNService
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

The ApplicationIconBadgeNumber is set to 17, as seen below.

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken 
{
    //[SettingsManager shared].apnToken = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:devToken encoding:NSSymbolStringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSString *apnToken = [devToken description];
    apnToken = [apnToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"< >"]];
    apnToken = [apnToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    _dataManager.apnToken = apnToken;
    NSLog(@"Device token is %@", devToken);
    NSLog(@"Device token is %@", apnToken);
    [self sendAPNToken];
    //app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 17;
```

Is that the reason for the badges? My developers are saying "Badges were turned off during registration in APNS, and it is an iOS error." Does that appear to be the case?

Comment: Why add the "app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 17;" if you don't want a badge? And yes it sounds like a bug.

Comment: The registration only turns of the ability for push notifications to set a badge, you can always change the badge in code.

Comment: PS: Why are you pushing badges if you don't want badges?

Comment: Would the registration be a server side issue, not visible in xcode or through my dev. account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badges can't really be "turned off". I don't know what your devs mean but I highly doubt it is an iOS error. You can set the number of badges to 0 like this:

```
app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Maybe they set the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to 17 and then commented out the line but never set it back to 0.

Comment: After changing the number to 0 and saving, what do I need to do to put the change into effect?

Comment: In the app delegate, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` use this `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];`. We don't need no stinkin' badges.

Comment: Apparently the badge is appearing from the very beginning, and the badge shows a 1. I say that, because though it is only 1 app, there are lots of individually controlled "sub-apps" within it who send out independent push notifications to their respective registered users. It appears to be a "1" regardless of what group they are registered with.